# how to generate unique values using sys_GUID() in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select (SELECT   UPPER(SUBSTR(SYS_GUID(), 1, 16)) FROM DUAL) AS N_EVTtt_ID
from testing
```

I am using the above query to generate the unique ID(GUID) which apparently is giving me the same value for my primary key **N_EVTtt_ID** . Please advice how to fix this?
The output for the above SQL query. I want all the IDs to be different.

```
AC87290F7D305666 
AC87290F7D305666
AC87290F7D305666
AC87290F7D305666
AC87290F7D305666
AC87290F7D305666
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: SYS_GUID() is a 32-character string. Why are you only using the first 16 characters? That makes zero sense, if the goal is to get distinct values.

Comment: Scalar subquery results are cached. Don't use a scalar subquery if you don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the subquery:

```
select UPPER(SUBSTR(SYS_GUID(), 1, 16)) AS N_EVTtt_ID
from testing
```

In an `INSERT`:

```
insert into some_table
select UPPER(SUBSTR(SYS_GUID(), 1, 16)) AS N_EVTtt_ID from testing
```

Comment: I need to insert it that is why I am selecting again; something like below.

Comment: insert into some_table  select (select UPPER(SUBSTR(SYS_GUID(), 1, 16)) AS N_EVTtt_ID
from testing ) as some_column